# Comparing the text in multiple files and keeping the same files in one location

Tags: python, duplicates

I have n text files with different name in a folder and I want to compare text present in the file with each other and if they are same then keep those in separate folder and delete from main folder. Can anyone help me?

My code so far:

```
file1=open("F1.txt","r")
file2=open("F2.txt","r")
file3=open("F3.txt","r")
file4=open("F4.txt","r")
file5=open("F5.txt","r")
list1=file1.readlines()
list2=file2.readlines()
list3=file3.readlines()
list4=file4.readlines()
list5=file5.readlines()
for line1 in list1:
    for line2 in list2:
        for line3 in list3:
            for line3 in list4:
                for line4 in list5:
                    if line1.strip() in line2.strip() in line3.strip() in line4.strip() in line5.strip():
                        print line1
                        file3.write(line1)
```

Comment: You should post your tried code and yes this is possible in python.

Comment: You could calculate a hash of the files and compare just the hash values. You might want to show us which effort you spend on solving your problem.

Comment: I tried following code
file1=open("F1.txt","r")
file2=open("F2.txt","r")
file3=open("F3.txt","r")
file4=open("F4.txt","r")
file5=open("F5.txt","r")

list1=file1.readlines()
list2=file2.readlines()
list3=file3.readlines()
list4=file4.readlines()
list5=file5.readlines()

for line1 in list1:
    for line2 in list2:
        for line3 in list3:
            for line3 in list4:
                for line4 in list5:
                    if line1.strip() in line2.strip() in line3.strip() in line4.strip() in line5.strip():
                        print line1
                        file3.write(line1)

Comment: The above code it not solving my purpose

Answer (score 0):

See [see if two files have the same content in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072569/see-if-two-files-have-the-same-content-in-python)

For comparing, you can use the filecmp module (http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html):

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('F1.txt, 'F2.txt')
True
>>> filecmp.cmp('F1.txt', 'F3.txt')
False
```

So one way to tackle it would be (not at all elegant but it does work):

```
import filecmp
files = ['F1.txt', 'F2.txt', 'F3.txt', 'F4.txt', 'F5.txt']
comparisons = {}
for itm in range(len(files)):
    try:
        res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+1])
        comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+1])] = res
    except:
        pass
    try:
        res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+2])
        comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+2])] = res
    except:
        pass
    try:
        res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+3])
        comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+3])] = res
    except:
        pass
    try:
        res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+4])
        comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+4])] = res
    except:
        pass
print(comparisons)
```

Gives:

```
{'F1.txt vs F2.txt': True, 'F1.txt vs F5.txt': False, 'F2.txt vs F4.txt': True, 
 'F3.txt vs F4.txt': False, 'F1.txt vs F4.txt': True, 'F2.txt vs F3.txt': False, 
 'F2.txt vs F5.txt': False, 'F1.txt vs F3.txt': False, 'F3.txt vs F5.txt': False, 
 'F4.txt vs F5.txt': False}
```

As for the other part of your question, you can use the built-in `shutil` and `os` modules like so:

```
import shutil
import os
if filecmp.cmp('F1.txt', 'F2.txt') is True:
    shutil.move(os.path.abspath('F1.txt'), 'C:\\example\\path')
    shutil.move(os.path.abspath('F2.txt'), 'C:\\example\\path')
```

UPDATE: better answer, modified from @zalew's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/748879/5247482

```
import shutil
import os
import hashlib
def remove_duplicates(dir):
    unique = []
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isfile(dir+'\\'+filename):
            print('--Checking ' + dir+'\\'+filename)
            filehash = hashlib.md5(filename.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
            print(filename, ' has hash: ', filehash)
            if filehash not in unique: 
                unique.append(filehash)
            else:
                shutil.move(os.path.abspath(filename), 'C:\\example\\path\\destinationfolder')
    return
remove_duplicates('C:\\example\\path\\sourcefolder')
```

Comment: Will it work for multiple files like 100 or 200? @Jon

Comment: Yes, but you will have 100 or 200 separate try/except statements.. better to have a recursive for loop

Comment: I would recommend this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/748879/5247482 from @zalew ... then you would just have another line `remove_duplicates(c:\\example\\path')` ... and edit the last line per my answer above `shutil.move(...)`

Comment: the files are not identical so I have to group similar files..will this work that case also? @http://stackoverflow.com/users/5247482/jon

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.. This will compare all files in a folder with all the other files in that folder and move the duplicates to a location you specify.

Comment: Oh I see ... you want to know if the files are similar (rather than exactly identical)?

Comment: Actually my files are not similar ...I can say that some words/lines are similar in the file which will be matching the other file.

Comment: The above will only work for exactly identical files. If they are similar, it will depend how similar... is it one word matching, or 50% of the words matching? Either way, the answers on your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34806231/5247482 will be a better solution for you

Comment: Can we use vector space model for this...?

Comment: Not familiar with that, but looks like it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8716778/5247482