# Comapring multiple text files and grouping similar files in one group

Tags: python

I have 100-200 text files with different name in a folder and I want to compare text present in the file with each other and keep the similar files in a group.

Note : 
1.Files are not identical. They are similar like 2-3 lines in a paragraph are same with other file.
2. one file may be kept in different groups or can be kept in multiple groups

Can anyone help me in this as I an beginner to python?

I have tried the below code but it doesn't work for me.

```
file1=open("F1.txt","r")
file2=open("F2.txt","r")
file3=open("F3.txt","r")
file4=open("F4.txt","r")
file5=open("F5.txt","r")
list1=file1.readlines()
list2=file2.readlines()
list3=file3.readlines()
list4=file4.readlines()
list5=file5.readlines()
for line1 in list1:
for line2 in list2:
    for line3 in list3:
        for line3 in list4:
            for line4 in list5:
                if line1.strip() in line2.strip() in line3.strip() in line4.strip() in line5.strip():
                    print line1
                    file3.write(line1)
```

Comment: Open each file and read it line by line. For each line add it to a dictionary with the line as key and an array of strings as value. If the key already exist then you append the filename to the string array. Then you can iterate through the keys in the dictionary and analyze which files they occur in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your purpose right, you should iterate over all of the text files in the library and compare each one with the other (in all possible combinations). The code should look something like this:

```
import glob, os
nl = [] #Name list (containing the names of all files in the directory)
fl = [] #File list (containing the content of all files in the directory, each element in this list is a list of strings - the list of lines in a file)
os.chdir("/libwithtextfiles")
for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"): #Using glob to get all the files ending with '.txt'
    nl.append(filename) #Appending all the filenames in the directory to 'nl'
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    fl.append(f.readlines()) #Appending all of the lists of line to 'fl'
    f.close()
for fname1 in nl:
    l1 = fl[nl.index(fname1)]
    if nl.index(fname1) == len(nl) - 1: #We reached the last file
        break
    for fname2 in nl[nl.index(fname1) + 1:]:
        l2 = fl[nl.index(fname2)]
        #Here compare the amount of lines identical, use a counter
        #then print it, or output to a file or do whatever you want
        #with it
        #e.g (according to what I understood from your code)
        for f1line in l1:
            for f2line in l2:
                if f1line == f2line: #Why 'in' and not '=='?
                    """
                    have some counter increase right here, a suggestion is having
                    a list of lists, where the first element is 
                    a list that contains integers
                    the first integer is the number of lines found identical 
                    between the file (index in list_of_lists is corresponding to the name in that index in 'nl') 
                    and the one following it (index in list_of_lists + 1)
                    the next integer is the number of lines identical between the same file
                    and the one following the one following it (+2 this time), etc.

                    Long story short: list_of_lists[i][j] is the number of lines identical 
                    between the 'i'th file and the 'i+j'th one.
                    """
                    pass
```

Note that your code doesn't utilize loops where it should, you could have had a list called `l` instead of `line1 - line5`.

Aside from that, your code is unclear at all, I assume the missing indentation (`for line2 in list2:` should be indent, including anything afterwards) and the `for line3 in list3: for line3 in list4: #using line3 twice` are accidental and happened copying the code to this site. You're comparing every line with every line in the other files?

You should, as my comment in the code suggest, have a counter to count in how many files does that line repeat (doing that by having a for-loop with another loop nested inside, iterating over the lines and comparing just two, rather than all five, where even when having `5` files, each with `10` lines, you'd iterate `100,000` times over it (`10**5`) - whereas in my method, you only have `1000` iterations in such case, `100` times more efficient).

Comment: We can use vector space model in this case...?

Comment: @Manuj It'd be highly inefficient relative to the above method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check similar lines in between files:

```
  import glob

  _contents = dict()
  for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
      file = open(filename, 'r')
      frd = file.readlines()
      _contents[filename]=frd

  for key in _contents:
     for other_key in _contents:
         if key == other_key:
             pass
         else:
            print("Comparing in between files {0} and {1}".format(key, other_key))
            non_identical_contents = set(_contents[key]) - set(_contents[other_key])
            print(list(set(_contents[key])-non_identical_contents))
```